# Many to Many relation with embedded key is inserting null in primary key

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

Facing problem inserting records in intermediate table.
Post and Tag tables are sharing many to many relationship using intermediate table post_tag;

Post table: id (pk), post, created_by, created_on, modified_by, modified_on

Tag table: id (pk), tag, created_by, created_on, modified_by, modified_on

Post_Tag table: post_id, tag_id (pk post_id and tag_id), created_by, created_on, modified_by, modified_on

Entities:

```
// ID class
@Embeddable @Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class PostTagId
    implements Serializable {
 
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Long postId;
 
    @Column(name = "tag_id")
    private Long tagId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "post_tag")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class PostTag extends Auditable<String> {
 
    @EmbeddedId
    private PostTagId id;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("postId")
    @JoinColumn(name="post_id")
    private Post post;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("tagId")
    @JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
    private Tag tag;
 
    public PostTag(Post post, Tag tag) {
     this.post = post;
     this.tag = tag;
     this.id = new PostTagId(post.getId(), tag.getId());
    }

  }
```

Using springboot(AuditingEntityListener) to add audit columns. Post and Tag entities are somewhat like -

```
///////////Tag
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude = {"postTags"})
    @ToString( exclude = {"postTags"})
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tag")
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    public class Tag extends Auditable<String> {
      @Id  
      private Long id;
      
      @Column(name = "tag")
      private String tag;
      
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
      private Set<PostTag> postTags;
    }

//////////////POST

    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude = {"postTags"})
    @ToString( exclude = {"postTags"})
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "post")
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    public class Post extends Auditable<String> {
      @Id  
      private Long id;
      
      @Column(name = "post")
      private String post;
      
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
      private Set<PostTag> postTags;
    
      public void addTag(Tag tag) {
        PostTag postTag = new PostTag(this, tag);
        if (postTags == null) {
          postTags = new HashSet<>();
        }
        postTags.add(postTag);
        tag.getPostTags().add(postTag);
      }
    }
```

Code snippet for insertion of tags using addTag() method -

```
public Post create(Post post) {
    // DefaultTag is some default tag getting from repository   
    post.addTag(DefaultTag)
    return postRepo.save(post);
  }
```

Insert in post_tag is trying to insert null post_id.

```
 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         post_tag
         (created_by, created_on, modified_by, modified_on, post_id, tag_id) 
     values
         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper SQL Error: 0, SQLState:
 23502 [0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  ERROR: null
 value in column "post_id" violates not-null constraint   Detail:
 Failing row contains (null, 100, anonymousUser, anonymousUser,
 2020-07-06 15:22:19.227-06, 2020-07-06 15:22:19.227-06).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed @EmbededId and used @Id in PostTag class. This way do not need to create embededId in constructor, and hibernate handles id creation. Changes look like this -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post_tag")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class PostTag extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {
 
    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name="post_id")
    private Post post;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
    private Tag tag;    
  }
```

Since *PostTag(Post, Tag)* constructor is removed, addTag(Tag tag) method needs to be refactored in Post entity.

```
    public void addTag(Tag tag) {
      PostTag postTag = new PostTag();
      postTag.setPost(this);
      postTag.setTag(tag);
      if (postTags == null) {
        postTags = new HashSet<>();
      }
      postTags.add(postTag);
      tag.getPostTags().add(postTag);
   }
```

Comment: I am also facing the similar problem. I could see spring jpa trying to set  null values in the link entity table.  Could you take a look at to see if I am missing some this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959365/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-many-to-many-relation-is-inserting-null-in-link-entit